# Slider in Bootstrap within IE is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I have implemented Bootstrap (Twitter) on my website and I am having a problem with the Slider. It is running fine in all the browsers except IE. Following is the error:

```
Message: 'target' is undefined
```

Following is the JS, which triggers the error:

```
$(this).find('.arrow-right').each(function (){
    $(this).bind(event_down, function (){
        content.swipe.next();
        if ($.browser.msie){
            var pos = target.swipe.getPos();
            var k = 0;
            pageview.children().each(function (){
                var act=k==pos;
            $(this).addClass((act?"":"in")+"active").removeClass((act?"in":"")+"active");
                k++;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

### Update

The upper code is from hammer.js which I used for gestures. When I removed this code, it still didn't work. So basically now no error is being thrown but all the slides are vertically displayed and the slider (ofcourse) is not working.

Comment: I am not sure how to see the version of the Bootstrap. The JS files have no version in them

Comment: See my Update, please/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is NOT browser or IE related. You only see this error on IE because you use target inside the `if ($.browser.msie)`. You have to use event.target where event is a variable bind event function.

To show:

```
<button id="button1">Click</button> 
<button id="button2">Click</button> 
</div>  

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button1').click(function(){
        alert(target.nodeName)
    }
);

$('#button2').click(function(event){
        alert(event.target.nodeName);
    }
);
```

The first button will cause the same error you got. In your case use `$(this).bind(event_down, function (event)` and `event.target.swipe.getPos();`

See also: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/